# XRDP Fullscreen Lag on Ubuntu 22.04.3 (aarch64) with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (aarch64). I have been able to successfully connect via XRDP from a Windows 10 machine (Session: Xorg), and the speed is well... satisfactory for most operations.

But, here's the snag: when I maximize applications like the terminal to full-screen, the performance takes a complete nosedive and becomes incredibly laggy and slow, making it quite frustrating to use.

I tried a bunch of stuff to make XRDP faster, but none really hit the mark:

1. Setting connection speed as LAN (10Mbits or higher) in Remote Desktop Connection
2. Turning animations off:

   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false`
3. Adjusting the following options in /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

   `use_compression = yes`

   `crypt_level=none`

   `max_bpp=16`

   `tcp_send_buffer_bytes=4194304`

   I also gave `sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=8388608` a shot, but after rebooting, it simply led to a black screen with no response...

Any help would be much appreciated :)

[image: Neofetch]

PS1: I did try RealVNC. It was even slower...

PS2: Any session in Remote Desktop Connection other than Xorg did not work and only resulted in a cyan screen (Xvnc, vnc-any, neutrinordp-any)